# Opening new browser window/tab inside AJAX/GWT application

Tags: ajax, gwt

I'm just wondering if it would be possible to open new browser window/tab inside AJAX/GWT application. For example: there is an application which takes all the space of one page, and in one part there is tabbed panel, so I would like to open fully functional browser window/tab inside that panel.

Is it possible somehow? Thank you for replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open).  In GWT, use [`Window.open()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html).

Neither of these have anything to do with AJAX, they are standard features of JavaScript/GWT.

Comment: The only thing you havent mentioned is that there is no solution to open tab.

Comment: There is no way to tell a browser to open a new tab instead of a new window. Whether to open in tabs or windows is a user preference, and some browsers don't have tabs at all.